# UserManager ignored in Django

Tags: python, django

Given this Django code in my `models.py`:

```
class ClientManager(UserManager):
    def create_user(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise(Exception)
        client = Super(UserManager, self).create_user(*args, **kwargs)
        return client

class Client(AbstractUser):
    objects = ClientManager()
```

How come no exception is raised when I create a Client user from the admin?

I've tried many variations on that principle, but no `create_user` ever seems to be used apart from the model's `__init__()`. Adding an exception in `django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user()` method also leads to the user being created without raising an exception, which seems to indicate that I'm missing something big, here.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.py?

Comment: I did not set AUTH_USER_MODEL because I want to use several types of users and it seemed like AUTH_USER_MODEL was designed to be only overridden for one type of user.

Comment: The admin uses the model defined in AUTH_USER_MODEL for it's operations, and if not defined, will have no way to know to use your custom class.

Comment: I see where my mistake was: I wanted to have the site administrators create any type of user directly; each would create a different user type deriving from the Django AbstractUser. But it seems I cannot have more than one user type that Django recognises for regular user operations. So, if I want to use specific user creation pages, I'll have to build them on my own, and link all of my metadata to one single, common Django user type, correct?